# Галерея наподобие закладок в Safari

Tags: javascript

Может кто-нибудь видел JavaScript-галерею, похожую на то, как выглядят закладки в браузере Safari (такую же изогнутую внутрь). Если кто видел что-нибудь похожее, подскажите ссылку, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Free Flash Templates](http://www.flashmo.com/page/1)  - вот тут посмотрите. Правда, там больше флэш, но именно изогнутая внутрь есть. Может, подойдет.